# Apply CSS to multiple elements with same class based on class of currently hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple elements on a page that have matching classes.  The classes are built by a variable so I can't hard code the css into a stylesheet.  The elements that make up the page will constantly change and so I need some javascript to find the element's class and then apply some css for that class.  It's on a site with Jquery, Drupal (views) if that helps at all...

I'm part of the way there.  I've written the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").hover(function() {
   var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
   $(.$myClass).hover(function(){
      $(this).css({
      border : '3px solid red',
      color : 'red'
      });
   });
});
});
```

Now if I put in there an 'alert', I see that it is capturing the class of the element that is currently being hovered over.  But I can't get it to then find all of the elements on the page with that class and apply the css.  To add some info, the two elements that I am trying to adjust are a small thumbnail image which I would like to add a border around, and the title of a linked node which I would like to change color.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do the elements only ever have *one* class-name, then?

Comment: Yes.  Each element gets its class by viewlink[nid] so they come out as viewlink1 or viewlink2 etc.

Comment: In which case use the native DOM methods: `var myClass = this.className;` it's easier to read, less typing is required and it's faster to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is two-fold (at least), but effectively you're declaring the variable:

```
var myClass =  $(this).attr("class");
```

And then trying to access that variable with a different name, `.$myClass`, when it should be:

```
$(.myClass)
```

Also, the period for the selector is not part of the variable name, it's a string, and as such must be quoted and concatenated:

```
$('.' + myClass)
```

Further, you're not assigning behaviour to those other elements on hover of *those* elements, but on hover of the `a` element you're currently hovering. So your

```
$("a").hover(function() {
   var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
   $(.$myClass).hover(function(){
      $(this).css({
      border : '3px solid red',
      color : 'red'
      });
   });
```

Should be:

```
$("a").hover(function() {
   var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
   $('.' + myClass).css({
      border : '3px solid red',
      color : 'red'
      });
   });
```

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work.  None of the css is applied.  If the anchor is inside other divs would that affect it?

Comment: Please show a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem, because I can't see why that shouldn't work (at least not at the moment).

Comment: Changed the  'var myClass = this.className;'

Comment: So I saw; since that should do the same thing (but faster) as you were already doing it wasn't *supposed* to change anything, except increase efficiency. Please post a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I've never used JS Fiddle before so I don't know if this is useful, but...http://jsfiddle.net/kKyTf/

Comment: Hi David, I do see some update on the JS Fiddle page, so could it be that something else is conflicting with the javascript attempt to apply the css?  And is there anyway to isolate the border to just the img and the color to just the text?  Thanks!

Comment: After correcting your demo (`class="mathcing1"` != `class="matching1"` and the trailing `})` at the end of your JavaScript) it [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kKyTf/10/).

Comment: By the way - I updated the javascript slightly from the first link I sent: http://jsfiddle.net/kKyTf/9/

Comment: And again: once the typo in the class-name of the `a` element is corrected, it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could something else (css or other divs or something) cause the javascript to not work on my full site?  I have the same code now on each but the full site still doesn't function like the JS Fiddle snippet.

Comment: Check your spellings, [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org), [validate your CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/), [check your JavaScript](http://jslint.com/). Make sure you've got a valid [Doctype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration).

Comment: Could you give me any insight into why the interaction of this works in one direction but not the other?  http://jsfiddle.net/vZAYY/14/  The images react when the text is hovered over but the text doesn't react when the image is hovered over.  I added an alert on my local site and it showed that the javascript isn't finding the element as it's returning -1.  Any advice?

Comment: Because you're basing the events on hovering over the `a` element.

Comment: what should I be basing the events on instead?

Comment: Please consider asking another question. Your questions here extend the scope of what's already been solved/answered.